# Creating DataGrid tooltips for only one column (different tooltip for each row)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I would like to create tooltips for my datagrid, but only for the first column, with every row on the column having a different tooltip text.

As my datagrid can display different kind of datasets (user selecting the right one using combobox), I think that the tooltips should be created in code-behind (instead of using some kind of binding)?

**Update:**

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DG_ConfigWindow" Height="253" Margin="0,37,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Loaded="DG_ConfigWindow_Loaded" 
    CellEditEnding="DG_ConfigWindow_CellEditEnding" IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="705" 
    PreviewKeyDown="DG_ConfigWindow_KeyDown" SelectionMode="Single" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False"> 
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="DG_ConfigWindow_MouseEnter"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=TooltipText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

Code:

```
private string _TooltipText;
public string TooltipText
{
    get { return _TooltipText; }
    set
    {
        _TooltipText = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}

private void DG_ConfigWindow_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TooltipText = "test";
}
```

INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

And my class is defined like this:

```
public partial class ConfigWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example shows you how to set up a `ToolTip`. In this case based on your need you can update the variable that I called `YourText` from code behind and change the `ToolTip`.

```
<DataGrid.ToolTip>
    <ToolTip Background="#FAFAFA">
         <FlowDocumentScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" MaxWidth="250" >
             <FlowDocument FontSize="12" LineHeight="16" FontFamily="Sagoe UI" IsOptimalParagraphEnabled="True" IsHyphenationEnabled="True">
                  <Paragraph>
                     <Run Text="{Binding Path=YourText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                   </Paragraph>
              </FlowDocument>
         </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
    </ToolTip>
</DataGrid.ToolTip>
```

Update:

Here is a way to get the element of `DataGrid` when you do `MouseOver`

First add an `EventSetter` in `Style` like below:

```
   <DataGrid.Resources>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
              <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="EventSetter_OnHandler"/>
         </Style>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
```

And the `Handler` should be like this:

private void EventSetter_OnHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)

```
    {
        DataGridCell dgc = sender as DataGridCell;

        TextBox tb = Utils.GetChildOfType<TextBox>(dgc);
        //I assumed you have TextBox for your cell. After finding the element you then need to implement your logic here to update the YourText variable here.

    }
```

This helper will help you find your cell

```
public static T GetChildOfType<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj == null) return null;

        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

            var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
            if (result != null) return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: That could work, if YourText can be updated depending on the row and column the cursor is placed upon. Is that possible?

Comment: For that you have to subscribe to mouse over for that datagrid cell and then change `YourText` in my example accordingly.

Comment: How to subscribe to that? And, in addition to just subscribing, I would need to get the "coordinates" of the cell (row and column indexes).

Comment: I updated the answer for you. Take a look at it and if it solved your problem don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get the row index of the cell, but I have no idea how to get the index of the column that is targeted. That's the last thing that I am missing!

Comment: The column index was easier to obtain than I thought: `int columnIdx = dgc.Column.DisplayIndex;` Thank you for your help!

Comment: I encountered one more problem: when I try to update `YourText` (i.e. `YourText = "test";`), the `ToolTip` completely disappears. I have set up PropertyChanged properly (it is working on another part of my program, on a `TextBox`); is there something else I have to take into account when updating the `ToolTip` text?

Comment: Did you implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your model? Are you using `MVVM` ?

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` is implemented, I think I am not using `MVVM`. I tried several different ways (in XAML) to show a `ToolTip`, but none of them work any better than your version.

Comment: Please share some of your code where is `YourText` is defined and how do you change it.

Comment: `<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="DG_ConfigWindow_MouseEnter"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=TooltipText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>`

Here `YourText` is defined as `TooltipText`. It is changed using

`private string _TooltipText;
public string TooltipText
{
    get { return _TooltipText; }
    set
    {
        _TooltipText = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}`

Comment: I am not sure if your implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` is correct. Take a look at this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface

Comment: I added my `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation to the question.

Comment: Finally I found the solution: I had to define `ToolTip` using `Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.TooltipText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}`, as `TooltipText` is not part of an object I use to populate `DataGrid`.